# Создание объекта с помощью класса в js и вызов методов

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вопрос из любопытства к знатокам javascript

Пусть есть простой класс

```
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    changeName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

И допустим, что мне нужно создать экземпляр класса User и сразу вызвать метод (понятно что так делать плохо, и лучше сначала поместить объект в переменную, а потом вызывать методы)

1. Есть ли какие-нибудь различия между вызовами

   ```
   var user = new User('Tom').getName();
   ```

   и

   ```
   var user = (new User('Tom')).getName();
   ```
2. Почему следующий вызов вернет undefined в user?

   ```
   var user = (new User('Tom')).changeName('Sam');
   ```

Comment: *Почему следующий вызов вернет undefined в user?* — потому что `changeName` возвращает `undefined` (нет return)

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо @АндрейNOP

Comment: *Есть ли какие-нибудь различия между вызовами* — нету

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нет.
2. 

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  changeName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

var user;
(user = new User('Tom')).changeName('Sam');
console.log(user);
```

или

```
  changeName(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: а напишете почему ваш код работает? или хотя бы пару строчек обяснения